# How to generalize a method?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to generalize the following code:

```
def fetchUrl = {
  try {
    val lineList = Source.fromURL(url).getLines.toList
    process(lineList)
  }
  catch {
    case ex: java.net.UnknownHostException => ex.printStackTrace()
  }
}
```

I want to be able to fetch URL's (fromURL) and files (fromFile) with the same method. Is it possible to generalize this code to archive this?

I figured I could use pattern matching for this but I don't know how.

```
def fetchSource(src: Source, str: String) = src match {
  case ??? => Source.fromURL(url).getLines.toList
  case ??? => Source.fromFile(str).getLines.toList
}
```

Is there a way to get this right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to have one method that will fetch a given `Source`, and two wrapper methods that build `Source` from `File` or `URL`.

```
def fetchSource(source: io.Source) =
  try {
    val lineList = source.getLines.toList
    process(lineList)
  } catch {
    case ex: java.net.UnknownHostException => ex.printStackTrace()
  }

def fetchFile(file: java.io.File) = fetchSource(io.Source.fromFile(file))

def fetchUrl(url: java.net.URL) = fetchSource(io.Source.fromURL(url))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if a string is a Url (for this example I'm using java.net.URL, but you can do it with [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) as well)

Something like this:

```
def isUrl(url: String) = try {
        new java.net.URL(url)
        true
    } catch {
        case _ => false
    }


import scala.io.Source

def fetchSource(src:String) = if(isUrl(src)) {
        Source.fromURL(src).getLines.toList
    } else {
        Source.fromFile(src).getLines.toList
    }
```